# Swift: Auto Text Layout in UIButton

Tags: swift, text, uibutton, autolayout, uilabel

I am working on an app with text in buttons. The text varies in length and should always be formatted correct in size and word wrap. 
I tried using numberOfLines but doesn't work well on smaller sentences. As you can see in the picture below.
Is there a nice way to get the text formatted the right way?

```
button.titleLabel!.font =  UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18)
button.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byClipping
button.titleLabel!.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
button.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 5
```

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you think the right way is?

Comment: As you see in the lower row "Best case, etc... " would look way better in just 3 rows. Or "spendieren" the n is in the next line which could be fixed using a smaller size of the font.

Comment: Have you tried this:
yourbutton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;